# javascript - transforming arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

how do I use Javascript to turn this list:

```
var array = ["no yes", "maybe certainly"];
```

into this one:

```
var array2 = ["no", "yes", "maybe", "certainly"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use `regex` here, if there are chances of multiple spaces in the array elements.

1. Join the array elements by space
2. Extract non-space characters from string using regular expression

```js
var array = ["       no yes     ", "     maybe     certainly  "];

var array2 = array.join('').match(/\S+/g);

document.write(array2);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Very simple, seems efficient.

Comment: @rrowland not so efficient http://jsperf.com/match-vs-split-22, as you can see `split` more faster than `match`

Comment: @Alexander You might want to recheck that again with updated answer. http://jsperf.com/match-vs-split-22/2

Comment: @Tushar as I see split faster than match http://jsperf.com/match-vs-split-22, and I can say much faster

Comment: @Alexander That is with the old code. I've updated code. Kindly check again on http://jsperf.com/match-vs-split-22/2

Comment: split - `var array2 = array.join('').trim().split(/\s+/g);` match `var array2 = array.join('').match(/\S+/g);` update your jsperf. and you will get result  http://jsperf.com/match-vs-split-22

Comment: @Tushar so, do you see difference ?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, but that is very very small, you can ignore that, right?

Comment: @Tushar no, I can't )

Answer (score 1):

You can [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) all elements in array, and after [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it to array, like so

```js
// var array = ["no yes", "maybe certainly"];
var array = ["no yes     ", "    maybe    certainly"];
var array2 = array.join('').trim().split(/\s+/g);

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["no yes", "maybe certainly"]

answer = converfunction(array);

function converfunction(array){
return array.toString().replace(',',' ' ).split(' ')
}
```

Comment: Check with `var array = ["       no        yes          ", "         maybe         certainly "];`